# Edge detection in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table where the value in each row can be one of two values, eg 0 or 1.  Each row also has an `ID` identity column.

What's the most efficient way to query the table to return the min and max `ID` values for each contiguous group of values?

Example:

```
declare @tbl table (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Value INT);

insert into @tbl (Value)
values (1), (1), (1), (0), (0), (1), (0), (0), (1), (1), (1), (1);
```

Table contents:

```
ID  Value
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   0
6   1
7   0
8   0
9   1
10  1
11  1
12  1
```

What I'd like to output from the query:

```
GroupID Value MinID MaxID
1       1     1     3
2       0     4     5
3       1     6     6
4       0     7     8
5       1     9     12
```

I've worked out a query to return these results.  However, it's inefficient as it has to run over the table 4x, twice to get the `MinID` values and twice again for the `MaxID` values.  As the real table I'll be running this query over has over 10 million rows, I'm looking for a more efficient query.

Here's the query I've worked out:

```
declare @maxID INT;
select @maxID = MAX(ID)
from @tbl;

select min.RowID AS GroupID, min.Value, min.MinID, max.MaxID
from 
    (
        select 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.ID) AS RowID, 
            x.Value, x.ID as MinID
        from @tbl x
            left join @tbl ld on x.ID = ld.ID + 1
                            and x.Value <> ld.Value
        where x.ID = 1
            or ld.ID is not null
    ) min
    join 
    (
        select 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.ID) AS RowID, 
            x.Value, x.ID as MaxID
        from @tbl x
            left join @tbl trl on x.ID = trl.ID - 1
                            and x.Value <> trl.Value
        where trl.ID is not null
            or x.ID = @maxID
    ) max
    on min.RowID = max.RowID
order by GroupID;
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following which uses *lag* to first identify where each group of values changes, then a running sum to create a sequential value for each group; with that in place you can then simply aggregate:

```
declare @tbl table (ID int identity(1,1), Value int);
insert into @tbl (Value)
values (1), (1), (1), (0), (0), (1), (0), (0), (1), (1), (1), (1);

with grp as (
  select *,
      case when Lag(Value) over(order by ID) = Value then 0 else 1 end gp
  from @tbl
), seq as (
  select *, Sum(gp) over(order by ID) s
  from grp
)
select
  s + 1 as GroupId,
  Value,
  Min(ID) MinId,
  Max(ID) MaxId
from seq
group by s + 1, Value
order by GroupId;
```

[fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/v1tIDEE0)

Comment: Works a treat, thank you.  On a table with about 15 million rows, hosted on my (not powerful at all) personal laptop, it took around 4 minutes to execute, which I think is acceptable performance for what I need.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use `s + 1` everywhere in the last select? I tried changing it to just `s` and it doesn't materially change the result set (and I might argue clarifies it as now the GroupID concept is 1-based enumeration)